# cmake package_search_module for glfw3 finds package, doesn't supply full lib path

Tags: cmake, homebrew, glfw

This seems pretty straightforward but I'm wasting enormous amounts of time getting it working. I just want to build and link a main.cpp file that includes glfw3.h, but cmake is not seeing the lib path for GLFW.  the call to package_search_module is providing the right include dir, but the resulting GLFW_LIBRARIES value only has the lib name 'glfw3' in it and its dir is not being given on the command line for the build.

What am I missing here?

Here is my very simple CMakeFiles.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(gltest)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE true)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(gltest ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(gltest ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})

message("GLFW_LIBRARIES=${GLFW_LIBRARIES}")
```

And here is the build output, where you can see at the top there that GLFW_LIBRARIES contains 'glfw3':

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /Users/dave/Library/Caches/CLion12/cmake/generated/7a31a53e/7a31a53e/Debug --target all -- -j 8
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -H/Users/dave/dev/gltest -B/Users/dave/Library/Caches/CLion12/cmake/generated/7a31a53e/7a31a53e/Debug --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
GLFW_LIBRARIES=glfw3
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/dave/Library/Caches/CLion12/cmake/generated/7a31a53e/7a31a53e/Debug
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /Users/dave/Library/Caches/CLion12/cmake/generated/7a31a53e/7a31a53e/Debug/CMakeFiles /Users/dave/Library/Caches/CLion12/cmake/generated/7a31a53e/7a31a53e/Debug/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/gltest.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/gltest.dir/depend
cd /Users/dave/Library/Caches/CLion12/cmake/generated/7a31a53e/7a31a53e/Debug && /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /Users/dave/dev/gltest /Users/dave/dev/gltest /Users/dave/Library/Caches/CLion12/cmake/generated/7a31a53e/7a31a53e/Debug /Users/dave/Library/Caches/CLion12/cmake/generated/7a31a53e/7a31a53e/Debug /Users/dave/Library/Caches/CLion12/cmake/generated/7a31a53e/7a31a53e/Debug/CMakeFiles/gltest.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/gltest.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/gltest.dir/build
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable gltest
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/gltest.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++11 -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/gltest.dir/main.cpp.o  -o gltest  -lglfw3 
ld: library not found for -lglfw3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [gltest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gltest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And, finally, here is the glfw3.pc pkg-config that is used for the pkg_search_module call:

```
prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/glfw3/3.2.1
exec_prefix=${prefix}
includedir=${prefix}/include
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib

Name: GLFW
Description: A multi-platform library for OpenGL, window and input
Version: 3.2.1
URL: http://www.glfw.org/
Requires.private:
Libs: -L${libdir} -lglfw3
Libs.private:  -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreVideo
Cflags: -I${includedir}
~
```

**Update: I got it working with this, but it still feels wrong**
cmake docs recommend against using link_directories, but I am able to make this work by using that and building up a list of link libraries:

```
set(LINK_LIBRARIES )

# GLFW lib
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GLFW_LIBRARY_DIRS})
set(LINK_LIBRARIES ${LINK_LIBRARIES} ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(gltest ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(gltest ${LINK_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `<XPREFIX>_LDFLAGS` (all required linker flag) and maybe `<XPREFIX>_LDFLAGS_OTHER` (all other linker flags) with `<XPREFIX>` = GLFW, acccording to the documentation https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FindPkgConfig.html